# Remove some property levels in deep object hierarchy

Tags: javascript

Here is the object I have :

```
var jsonData = {
    "a" : {
        "0" : {
            "b" : {},
            "c" : {},
            "d" : {
                "0" : {
                    "e" : {},
                    "f" : {},
                    "g" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove the "0" and turn it like this?

```
var jsonData = {
    "a" : {
        "b" : {},
        "c" : {},
        "d" : {
            "e" : {},
            "f" : {},
            "g" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the JSON tag as there's no JSON in the question.

Comment: i use JSON.stringify but its not working

Comment: AldrenTerante, maybe the comment is stupid but your question is also stupid. If you want to remove the "0" just remove! Make another object  pattern and remove it. No other solution! And try to be more polite...

Comment: @AldrenTerante JSON is a format allowing serialization of javascript objects (or arrays) into text. What you have here isn't JSON but a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: @dystroy thank you for clarifying this things and also for your answer. I really learn alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build a recursive function :

```
var jsonData = {
    "a" : {
        "0" : {
            "b" : {},
            "c" : {},
            "d" : {
                "0" : {
                    "e" : {},
                    "f" : {},
                    "g" : {},
                    "h" : 3 // added to be less trivial
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function cloneWithout0(v){
  if (typeof v !== "object") return v;
  var c = {};
  for (var k in v) {
    if (k !== '0') c[k] = cloneWithout0(v[k]);
  }
  if (v['0']) {
    for (var k in v['0']) {
      if (k !== '0') c[k] = cloneWithout0(v['0'][k]);
    }
  }
  return c;
}

console.log(cloneWithout0(jsonData));
```